# Find time complexity for recursive function $T(n) = T(n-1) + (\log(n))^2, T(0) = 1$

Tags: asymptotics

I tried to unwinding the recursive function, but I got a

$T(n) = 1 + (\log(1))^2 + (\log(2))^2 + ... + (\log(n-1))^2 + (\log(n))^2$

How can I simplify it, or can I get time complexity from other way?

Comment: Hint: $T(n) = 1+\sum_{i=1}^n \log^2(i)$, which is awfully similar to $1+\int_{1}^n \log^2(x)dx$.

Comment: You won't get an exact closed form. But luckily, "complexity" only requires you to get a result [of the form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) $T(n)\in\Theta(f(n))$.

Comment: Hi Kolja, I did some calculation, the integration is equal to x(logx)^2 - 2xlogx + 2x + C, so my answer should be O(n(logn)^2)? can you please have a look, Is my thought correct?